# Can you make console commands through Alienware Alpha?

Tags: steam, windows

If so is it still possible to do it through Steam? (Since you obviously need to use steam to play on the Alpha...)

Comment: Alienware Alpha is a laptop; what game are you asking about?

Comment: @Frank Actually, it's a steam box.

Comment: Huh.  So it is.  Missed that.

Comment: @Frank I think what he MIGHT be asking is if Steam Boxes still support console commands? Specifically Steam OS? It's anyone's guess. Downvoted until author provides clarity.

Comment: Could be.  But that actually brings up a good point; these boxes aren't out yet.  We don't answer questions about things that haven't been released.  This could be a moot point, once the hardware is released.

Comment: Very true. Considering that Steam Boxes are just re-shelled laptops running Steam OS, I'm going to guess that they'd run the same Steam App as PCs. That would lead me to assume functionality is the same. However, in their page on the Steam Console, https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=3041-SHZN-9384 , Valve doesn't mention Steam boxes, so we have no way of knowing currently. I think this is off topic.

Comment: It sounds like he's asking if he's able to run linux commands even though its running steam os

Comment: @TheFaster it's not a Steam Box yet, as it runs Windows. It will support SteamOS when that's released, however. At the moment, the Alpha definitely exists so this question should be reopened

Answer (score 0):

The Alienware Alpha supports keyboard input even when you're using the console UI. I can't say whether Steam big picture mode will allow you to open a console in a game when it's running, but if it does then you will be able to enter console commands.

This assumes that you're referring to console commands in games - you might want to edit your question to make it more clear.